# Converting a List of String to List of Double without losing information (VB.net)

Tags: string, vb.net, list, types, double

I got a List of String. I am losing information (the dot) when I try to convert an entry to type Double. What am I doing wrong?

```
 Dim list As New List(Of String)
 Dim a As Double

 list.Add("309.69686")
 a = CDbl(list(0))
 MsgBox(a)
'Output: 30969686
```

Comment: In your country what is the separator between the integer part of a number and its decimal part?

Comment: Thank you steve, that was the problem. I am from Austria, so the separator is a comma and not a dot. Obvious stuff somehow lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in your locale the separator for decimal numbers is probably not a point but something else (usually a comma).
You are using the old VB6 methods to convert this string to a double and this method (CDbl) has no way to use a different locale settings.

So in the most basic form you need to change that method to the native .NET methods

```
a = Double.Parse(list(0), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Here we pass the information about what locale setting Parse should use in converting the input string to a double. And the InvariantCulture uses the point as separator.

Of course, you should consider that, if the input string is obtained from the user input, then you could face other problems (like invalid numeric strings). In this case you should not use double.Parse, but double.TryParse

Comment: Really? Old vb6? From the docs "As a rule, you should use the Visual Basic type conversion functions in preference to the .NET Framework methods"..." The Visual Basic functions are designed for optimal interaction with Visual Basic code" There is a separate note concerning localization so in this situation you are correct but I don't see why you reject `CInt` etc. in general.

Comment: Sorry but I think that these methods are too babysitting me. Like in _a = CInt(Nothing)_ , then if you need to work with C#, you stump badly on these

Answer (score 0):

If you have a German Windows, then the dot will be interpreted as thousands separator. You must specify the culture explicitly, if you need another behaviour.

```
Dim d = Double.Parse("309.69686", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```